# Advanced Custom Fields inside a plugin

Tags: wordpress, carousel, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having some problems receiving data from the ACF plugin inside a plugin.
I'm using owl carousel to display a slideshow but i would like to add some extra text fields per image.

I created 2 caption fields in ACF and linked them to the post type of Owl Carousel.

implemented the fields inside the Owl Carousel main php file like so:

```
    $caption1 = get_field('owl_caption1');
$caption2 = get_field('owl_caption2');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();

    $the_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $type);
    $result .='<div class="item"><img title="' . get_the_title() . '" src="' . $the_url[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '"/><p>'.$caption1.'</p><p>'.$caption2.'</p></div>';
```

I also added the include line to the top of this document (plugins/owl-carousel/owlcarousel.php) to receive the date but when i fill in the fields they are not displaying

```
include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );
```

The Faq of ACF states that you need to include the files inside your theme (themes/themename/advanced-custom-fields) or plugin (plugins/owl-carousel/advanced-customfields) so i tried copying the acf folder to my theme folder and the Owl Carousel plugin folder but i can't seem to receive the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you move the `get_field()` calls after `$loop->the_post();`?  Perhaps the global `$post` isn't set as you require when you make your `get_field()` calls

Comment: that doesn't seem to do the trick if i put it behind it

Comment: Where are those ACF fields created? On the ACF instaled on the WP or they are defined inside the other plugin? I never test this, but on the FAQs says this too: "To use PHP to register fields, please create a field group as per usual and use the ‘Export to PHP’ tool to generate your code", did you tried that?

Comment: No that didn't seem to be the problem. The solution was actually really simple/ stupid of me. I integrated the advanced custom fields plugin wrong, it needed to go up one more folder to the plugin directory instead of including the whole plugin inside the Owl,carousel plugin.

Like this:

include_once('../advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );

Instead of:

include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );

Thanks for the respose anyway :)